MySql remoto Cpanel
estoy teniendo problemas para conectarme a una base de datos que tengo alojada en MySql Cpanel, lo estoy intentando por dos medios, un codigo php que tengo en visual studio en mi pc (solo para ver si hay respuesta de conexion), y HeidiSql.
En ambos me da el siguiente error:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder
Quiero añadir que revise guias y demas para lograrlo, crear una nueva base de datos, y crear el usuario, luego dar acceso a mi ip o con el comodin "%" en la pestaña "MySQl remoto", y conectarlo con la ip del servidor.
Probe con una base de datos local, y el codigo php funciona correctamente. Me gustaria que me ayuden con alguna sugerencia o que podria hacer, gracias.

Hola. Si vas a interactuar a menudo con la base de datos remota te recomendaría que configures un acceso mediante un túnel SSH, asumiendo que el servidor donde está la base de datos permite ese tipo de acceso. La configuración inicial puede ser medianamente compleja: 1. Tienes que crear un par de llaves pública/privada en el servidor remoto; 2. Tienes que descargar del servidor la clave privada que guardarás en tu equipo local; 3. Tienes que configurar el host en tu equipo local y autorizarlo ... Luego te podrás conectar al servidor remoto, a todo él, no solamente ...

... a la base de datos, de una forma simple. Imaginemos que al configurar el host le llamaste hostUnNombre, si escribes en la consola ssh hostUnNombre te conectarás al servidor remoto con una gran ventaja respecto a la seguridad: no tendrás que poner el usuario / contraseña ni habilitar conexiones remotas a la BD que son una puerta abierta a usuarios mal intencionados. Esto es posible porque la conexión se identifica con la llave privada.

Otra ventaja es la rapidez, al estar conectado por consola, podrás hacer operaciones con más fluidez, sin tener que pasar por interfaces gráficas. Hablamos de cualquier tipo de operación, desde conectar a la BD, sincronizar archivos, etc. Y, si tuvieras algún cliente que quieres usar, también lo puedes configurar para que se conecte usando el túnel, conservando la gran ventaja de no estar metiendo usuario / contraseña cada vez. Ah, otra cosa, el archivo de la llave privada debe tener un nivel de seguridad adecuado cuando lo guardes en tu dispositivo local.

Por si te interesa esa opción te dejo este enlace con información detallada sobre cómo funcionan los túneles SSH y cómo se configuran. Si el servidor remoto está en hosting compartido no tienes que configurar tú la parte del servidor (ni podrás porque no tienes acceso de administrador), pero suele estar configurado y sólo tendrías que autorizar la conexión desde cPanel y descargar el archivo con la llave privada. Y finalmente hacer tu configuración local.

El firewall debe permitr acceso por el puerto correspondiente (generalmente el 3306) y el MySql debe permitir conexiones externas, creo recordar que esto se hace en el mysqld.cnf`` en el campo bind-adress`. Por último, también debes establecer los permisos al usuario

Primer paso:  Prueba un "telnet  3306" y mira si te devuelve algo o se queda colgado o te rechaza la conexión.  Si eso lo superas entonces asegúrate que tu IP está bien puesta en el "MySQL Remoto" de cpanel, y reverifica tu usuario y contraseña, y deberias poder pasar.  Si no pasas el primer paso puede ser porque no has puesto bien la IP en el "MySQL Remoto" o bien porque tu proveedor de hosting no permite esas conexiones remotas a ese puerto en su firewall, o bien tu propio dispositivo no las permite.

Son varias cosas las que pueden estar pasando, pero creo que, dando por hecho que has abierto bien el acceso externo a la base de datos, y que has configurado bien el cliente (VS ó Heidi), la más probable es que el puerto 3306 esté cerrado, ya sea por el firewall del servidor, o por el proveedor de hosting.
